# Perform overlap add with available FFT size smaller than filter coefficients

Tags: fft, real-time, matched-filter, fast-convolution, overlap-add

I would like to process 12 to 20 seconds of incoming audio at a sample rate of 44100. I must process this audio in real time in an STM embedded kit (perhaps also an Android Smartphone). I'm trying to detect and count the number of occurrences of a signal of roughly 6500 samples inside the incoming audio. The maximum FFT available is of 1024 samples.

I was thinking about applying overlap-add but the number of coefficients would be 6500 and that's larger than maximum FFT size of 1024. I tried to simulate this in Matlab using fftfilt but the function help says:

**If you supply a value for n, fftfilt chooses an FFT length, nfft, of 2^nextpow2(n)and a data block length of nfft - length(b) + 1. If n is less than length(b), fftfilt sets n to length(b).**

This makes me think that I'm forced to use an FFT of at least 6500 samples (which I can't) and then process 1 incoming audio sample at a time (super inefficient).

What can I do?

Comment: So you want to replace a matched filter (of length 6500 samples) detector with FFT (of length 1024) ?

Comment: Along with the technique pointed out by Stanley in his answer below, another option is partitioned convolution. Split your long filter into shorter sections and implement each as a separate filter. Then, delay and sum the filter outputs appropriately to reconstruct the response you would have gotten from using the long filter to begin with.

Comment: are you filtering with an FIR filter of 6500 taps?  is that what you're doing.  is this a **matched filter** problem?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Yes i'm sorry I didn't add matched filter tag as well!

Comment: @Fat32 In deed I want to be able to detect my signal of interest inside the large audio using a matched filter

Comment: okay, you will probably want to split your 6500-tap FIR into maybe 16 segments.  you need to pad the impulse response segment with lotsa zeros because the length of the zeros is the amount of samples you can process each frame.  so you'll be running 16 different 1024-point FFTs "simultaneously".

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson So 6500/16 = 407 samples from the original FIR inside 1024 samples hence 617 zeros every frame? And the what, perform the fast filtering of audio chunk with 16 matched filters of size 1024 and add the 16 outputs? Would you mind explaining all this step by step in an answer?

Comment: @JasonR Nice idea!

Comment: the whole thing is **one** matched filter.  but you are evaluating 617 samples of your output in each frame doing it in 16 smaller jobs.  BTW, are saying to us that in an Android phone, we can't do an FFT bigger than 1024 points??

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson no I'm not saying that! In Android I can in https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4discovery.html I have limitations, perhaps not 1024 but 4096

Answer (score 3):

You can make a big FFT out of smaller FFTs

This code implements a 16384 point FFT with a 16 point FFT and  1024 point FFT.

You need only calculate the Twiddle matrix once.

```
clear all
M=16;
N=1024;
x=sin(linspace(1,M*N,M*N)*2*pi*60/(M*N));  % test signal
X=reshape(x,N,M).'; % form 2D matrix read data in as rows
Twiddle=zeros(size(X));    % make Twiddle matrix
for i=1:M
for k=1:N   
Twiddle(i,k)=exp(-1j*2*pi*(i-1)*(k-1)/(N*M));
end
end
X=fft(X); % fft on each column
X=X.*Twiddle;% element by element product
X=fft(X.').' ; %fft on each row
y=reshape(X,N*M,1); % read out as columns
figure(1)
plot(abs(y),'linewidth',2)
title('Composite DFT')
figure(2)
plot(abs(fft(x)),'linewidth',2)
title('Direct DFT')
```

which is based on a section in

Rabiner, Lawrence R., and Bernard Gold. "Theory and application of digital signal processing." Englewood Cliffs, NJ, Prentice-Hall, Inc.,
1975. 777 p. (1975).

I don't have the book handy for a page number, but the section is the table of contents under something like 1D DFT as a 2D FFT.

update

section 6.8 page 371
A unified approach to the fft

Comment: Chapter 6 deals with FFT and discusses various decompositions. Yet no exact page shows the algorthm alone. It's distributed across the sections.

Comment: I have just downloaded the book could you please name the section